# Что можно взять в качестве шаблона/заготовок для микросервисного приложения?

Tags: devops

Всем привет. Я работаю DevOps инженером и хочу сделать портфолио, по которому можно будет понять что я умею касаемо DevOps (по стеку: k8s, Jenkins, Ansible). Разработать микросервисное приложение с нуля, чтобы потом под него сделать DevOps, для меня является необъятной задачей, потому что таких навыков именно разработки у меня нет (я учила Go, Python, PHP, C++, react; мои проекты - телеграм-боты, парсер+графики). Что я могу использовать в качестве шаблона/заготовок? Кажется, если я возьму просто любой проект с Github и буду делать под него, то это будет неэффективно.